# How do I find out what CSS is determining the dimensions of my React header component?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, google-chrome-devtools

Using View -> Developer -> Inspect Elements in Chrome, I can see the dimensions of my React header component:
[image]

When I "toggle device toolbar", it looks like this:
[image]
(Which is how it looks in Chrome or Safari on my iPhone.)

How do I figure out what is determining that narrow width on my phone?

**Update:** [xadm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124657/xadm), I was curious enough to click on `Computed`, but maybe not clever enough to see how to use it? I see how it shows the dimensions, but I don't see how it shows how the dimensions are determined:
[image]

Comment: never clicked on `computed`? no curiosity? really?

Comment: Maybe it isn't about curiousity, @xadm. Incredible assumption.

Comment: The `.container` classname is meant to have `.row` elements as children. You have a nested `.container` in there and no `.row`s. What are you trying to create?

Comment: when not defined explicitely (no list of property `width` or `min-width` changes in computed) ... it can depend on a few sources: `display` type, parent's declarations, inner element sizes (img in this case - you can add display:none to hide img temporary), or remaining space in row - declarations may wary on resolutions (media queries - style/rule dis-/appears)

Comment: Also the [`nav` in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/) is not meant to be a descendant of `.container`. Try removing that outer `.container` class.

Comment: create living [example] on publicly available/shareable editor like codesandbox

Comment: I think—it's been many months—I was using <Container> components because I misunderstood why they were being used in the code I adapted mine from. I'm removing them all and re-testing, then I'll update my question.

Comment: I reviewed all the places I used `<Container>` and replaced them all with `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to `body { ... }` in my main.scss:

```
min-width: 800px;
```

...and my page (especially the header) looks much better:
[image]

I arbitrarily chose 800px since it was double the "default" width to the right of `Responsive` when I toggle the device toolbar. Is there a way to determine an appropriate min-width?